# RSpec: Match an array of strings by regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am testing validation of my models with rspec and am expecting an error message. However, the exact text of the message is likely to change, so I want to be a bit more forgiving and only check for a partial message.

Since the Spec::Matchers::include method only works for strings and collections, I'm currently using this construct:

```
@user.errors[:password].any?{|m|m.match(/is too short/)}.should be_true
```

This works but seems a bit cumbersome to me. Is there a better (i.e., faster or more ruby-like) way to check an array for the inclusion of a string by regex, or perhaps an rspec matcher that does just this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend doing

```
@user.errors[:password].to_s.should =~ /is too short/
```

Simply because it will give you a more helpful error when it fails. If you use `be_any` then you get a message like this...

```
Failure/Error: @user.errors[:password].should be_any{ |m| m =~ /is too short/}
    expected any? to return true, got false
```

However, if you use the `to_s` method then you will get something like this:

```
 Failure/Error: @user.errors[:password].to_s.should =~ /is too short/
   expected: /is to short/
        got: "[]" (using =~)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -/is too short/
   +"[]"
```

So you can see the reason for the failure and don't have to go digging much to figure out why it is failing.

Comment: This is the version I've always used and it works well.  I agree with the difficulty of figuring out what went wrong from the ambiguous error message when you use `be_any`

Answer (score 20):

Using [RSpec 3 `expect` syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher) with [matchers composing](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/composing-matchers):

To match all:

```
expect(@user.errors[:password]).to all(match /some message/)
```

To match any:

```
expect(@user.errors[:password]).to include(match /some message/)
expect(@user.errors[:password]).to include a_string_matching /some message/
```

Comment: That's not quite correct. I want **at least one** of the password errors to match the string, but not necessarily **all**.

Comment: My bad. Then `expect(@user.errors[:password]).to include(match /some message/)` or even better `expect(@user.errors[:password]).to include a_string_matching /some message/`

Answer (score 9):

You can put the following code in spec/support/custom_matchers.rb

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :include_regex do |regex|
  match do |actual|
    actual.find { |str| str =~ regex }
  end
end
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
@user.errors.should include_regex(/is_too_short/)
```

and be sure you have something like this in spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it makes a performance difference, but a more RSpec-like solution would be

```
@user.errors[:password].should be_any { |m| m =~ /is too short/ }
```

Comment: As for docs, check out http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.0.1/frames. `be_any` is dynamically generated from the `any?` predicate, which comes from `Enumerable`.

Comment: I can see how `any?` converts to `be_any`, but it doesn't sound like good English.

Comment: To be precise, `be_any` does not "come from" `any?`. Calling `be_any` will dynamically create a `Matcher` which will call `any?`.

Comment: I actually found this solution is less than ideal after using it for a bit so I added a new answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Both above answer are good. I would, however, use the newer Rspec `expect` syntax

```
@user.errors[:password].to_s.should =~ /is too short/
```

becomes

```
expect(@user.errors[:password].to_s).to match(/is too short/)
```

More great info here: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is similar to @muirbot's. I use a custom matcher. However, I use the real `include` matcher, but augment it with the custom matcher as an argument. Load this somewhere before your suite runs (e.g. in spec/support/matchers.rb, in turn loaded by spec/spec_helper.rb):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define(:a_string_matching) do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual =~ expected
  end
end
```

Then your expectation can be written like this:

```
expect(@user.errors[:password]).to include(a_string_matching(/is too short/))
```

Comment: `a_string_matching` [is already part of RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/3b8d6a55d75d02039f3b95555690d9f987da1f82/lib/rspec/matchers.rb#L677) so no need to define it. Composing matchers is supported from RSpec 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

```
@user.errors[:password].grep /is too short/
```